# 2005 SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2005

Can someone interpret this query. I am aware that alias, conversion, and linked databases are involved, but not familiar placement of numbers "4,2".

```
set birthday = convert(datetime, left(a.dob,2)+ '/'+ 
               right(left(a.dob,4),2)+'/'+ 
               right(a.dob,2)+left(right(a.dob,4),2)) 
from 
  [plkfsql2k5\prod2k5].st_data.dbo.st_patient a
```

Comment: You are not familiar with this: `right(left(a.dob,4),2)` ?

Answer (score 1):

This `left(a.dob,2)+ '/'+right(left(a.dob,4),2)+'/'+right(a.dob,2)+left(right(a.dob,4),2)` nightmare of a substring concatenation is taking a date, probably stored as text (ugh) and returning it in a format that can be converted to a date with the `convert(datetime, <textdate)` formula it's wrapped in.

The text date appears to be in a format where the month is in the first 2 characters, the day is in the 3 and 4th characters and the year... well the years is stored instead of `1999` like `9919` because some psychopath designed this field...

So it takes this mmddyyYY format (that only a crazy person would use) and coverts it to mm/dd/YYyy and the n uses the `convert(datetime, <text date>)` function to make it into an actual date.

Note that if you are in a country that uses dd/mm/yyyy format, then my explaination may need to be tweaked as the incoming text value may be ddmmyyYY and converts it to dd/mm/YYyy. Still a crazy-banana's starting point though.

Comment: Great explanation of the whole thing - just in case @sclass needs some more basic information, though, [this page](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/tip-of-the-day.aspx?tkey=D0DD25A9-9BB6-43D6-B7B8-B592B1AD026D&tkw=uses-of-the-left-string-function) will explain what the `LEFT()` and `RIGHT()` functions actually do with the 4 and 2 :)

Comment: That helps. Thanks to you both.